# C++ Not find members

Tags: c++

Error message：
"std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>" No members  "isSubsequence".

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    bool isSubsequence(string s, string t) {
        if(s.size()<t.size()) return false;
        unordered_map<char,int> window,need;
        for(char c:s) need[c]++;
        int left=0,right=0;
        int sum=0;
        while(right<t.size()){
            char c = t[right];
            right++;
            if(need.count(c)){
                window[c]++;
                if(window[c]==need[c]){
                    sum++;
                }
            }
            if(sum==need.size()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main(){
    
    string s = "abc";
    string t = "ahbgdc";
    Solution s;
    s.isSubsequence(s,t);    
    return 0;
}
```

Why can't object s call class member functions？

Comment: `string s` and `Solution s` are there, so which `s` is in `s.isSubsequence(s,t)`?  Your compiler should complain about conflicting declaration. https://godbolt.org/z/7jc3dP

Comment: Always look at the *first* compiler error, since the subsequent ones can be (and often are) caused by that. In this case, the first error would be something like "*error: conflicting declaration 'Solution s'*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a naming conflict here:

```
string s = "abc";
//     ^
string t = "ahbgdc";
Solution s;
s.isSubsequence(s,t);
^               ^
```

Probably you wanted to do:

```
string str = "abc";
string t = "ahbgdc";
Solution s;
s.isSubsequence(str, t);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the same name for both the string and the solution object this is likely causing the name conflicts

Answer (score 2):

You have conflicting variable names. You have a `string` object named 's' and a `Solution` object named 's'. You mean to call the isSubsequence method on the `Solution` object, but it's being run on the `string` object instead. Simply change the variable names and you should be good.